# Symfony 3 FOSUserBundle doesn't send mail

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle, registration

I have a little problem lately with FOSUserBundle. Since last week it doesn't send any email while my Swift Mailer config is functional; I can send mail through a contact form. The only modification I made is adding some fields in the **parameters.yml** file.

Here is my **config.yml**:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
  default_mailer: mailer_1
  mailers:
    mailer_1:
      transport: '%mailer_transport%'
      encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
      auth_mode:  '%mailer_auth_mode%'
      host: '%mailer_host%'
      username: '%mailer_user%'
      password: '%mailer_password%'
      port: '%mailer_port%'
      sender_address: '%mailer_name%'
      spool:
           type: file
           path: '%kernel.project_dir%/spool'

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    service:
            mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
      address: '%mailer_user%'
      sender_name: '%mailer_name%'
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template:   '@FOSUser/Registration/email.txt.twig'
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
    resetting:
            email:
                template:   '@FOSUser/Resetting/email.txt.twig'
    profile:
        form:
          type: AppBundle\Form\ProfileFormType
```

I know that the mail in `fos_user` has to be the same in `swiftmailer`, and here it is. Any idea?

Comment: Try to subscribe to one of the email asociated events of FOSUserBundle, specifically to **RESETTING_SEND_EMAIL_INITIALIZE** and **RESETTING_SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRM** and post the result of the events to see what is really happenning behind. After post the results in order to provide a proper answer for you

Comment: I'm really bad subscribing to events. I make it for INITIALIZE but not to CONFIRM. And what to you mean by posting the result of the events ? You want a dump($event) ?

Comment: Make it to confirm, and yes a dump or a log which tells you what's happenning or not happening. Is the email getting to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `parameters.yml` file, you may not have configured your smtp infos correclty. If you want to use the `mail()` function of php, you must configure your `php.ini` according your server's configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think my parameters.yml are fine as through my contact form using \Swift_message, the email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your parameters.yml like this:

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: mail
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user:
    mailer_password:
```

It worked for me (Symfony 3.4), but depending of the receiver it could arrive in SPAM.

Comment: As the only modification you did is in parameters.yml, what lines did you add ?

Comment: I added 2  emails at the end of the file, like newsletter_user - newsletter_password - contact_user - contact_password